# spring boot application run, but I get error 404 in the web browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

spring boot application run, but I get 404 error in web browser, for frontend I have used jsp. The app was developed in spring mvc then I converted it to spring boot. after conversion is run as expected, but I do not see the data in browser. **"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Thu May 28 18:07:37 GMT-06:00 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"**

I have a WebMvcConfigurer class, it contains my view resolver do I needs it?
Thymeleaf does not need a view Reslover, is it the same for jps, too?
here my class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;

import thursday.com.todolist.util.ViewNames;



public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private static final String RESOLVER_PREFIX = "/templates/WEB-INF/view/";
    private static final String RESOLVER_SUFFIX = ".jsp";

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix(RESOLVER_PREFIX);
        viewResolver.setSuffix(RESOLVER_SUFFIX);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName(ViewNames.HOME);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you do need the suffix and prefix for the view resolver as the internal view resolver uses the prefix and suffix to make a logical mapping for your view , but you could also provide it in the `application.properties` file like :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/classes/templates
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

Also, Embedded Tomcat package (which is used in springboot to create executable jar)does not include JSP by default, we must add the module “`org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper`” as dependency as well.The reason why we are adding tomcat-embed-jasper as dependency in springboot, is that we can use the jstl tags in jsp.The jsp files needs to be transpiled into html.

- Also, since you moved to spring-boot from spring mvc make sure you
  removed the annotation `@EnableWebMvc` from your project as this will
  disable all spring-boot autoconfigurations.Unless, you are explicitly providing it yourself to handle all configurations manually like in spring-mvc.
- Also spring-boot and JSP quite doesn't work together with `jar` as the packaging so try to use `war` packaging if you are using jsp as the view template.The contents of the webapp folder is automatically taken up during build **only** if you keep the packaging as `war` .